# Failed to package flutter xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am trying to run my flutter project on my ios device, but I got an error in the xcode that says `"Failed to package /Users/user/StudioProjects/project."`

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and solved it by running my ios app on Android studio first then after that, I was able to run it on Xcode. It worked for me. It is weird but I don't know what was wrong. If this does not help, do this:

run flutter clean,

then flutter pub get,

finally pod update.

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed this:
This is because some of the image is corrupt but if you delete the corrupt image it won't solve the issue

Try:

- Delete the image -> flutter clean -> flutter pub get -> pod install (in iOS folder)

Note if you don't know what image is corrupt, try delete multiple of them one time

Answer (score 0):

Try
Upgrade flutter to latest version it is worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).